# No callback error shown when using bcrypt-node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am have created a node library file called `encrypt.js`.

Within that are some functions created using bcrypt-nodejs

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

exports.cryptPassword = function(password, callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        else {
            bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                return callback(err, hash);
            });
        }
    });
};

exports.comparePassword = function(password, userPassword, callback) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, userPassword, function(err, isPasswordMatch) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        else return callback(null, isPasswordMatch);
    });
};
```

When I now use `cryptPassword` from my `server.js` file it shows an error coming from the `bcrypt-nodejs` library stating '`no callback function was given`'

I have added a function within my call as below

```
var encryptedPassword =  encrypt.cryptPassword(req.body.user.password, function (err, salt){
    if(err) {throw err};
    console.log('hlllll');
});
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Syntax: `bcrypt.hash(data, salt, progress, cb)`

You must have two callbacks.

Document here:

https://npmjs.org/package/bcrypt-nodejs

---

Update:

You can use the package `bcrypt` instead of `bcrypt-nodejs`

And your code will work:

```
bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
   return callback(err, hash);
});
```

Comment: Silly that it says that all arguments *besides* `progress` are required, since it's obviously also required.

Comment: @robetklep Ah yes, I am trying, I think when there is only 1 callback, that callback should be the `result callback` not the `progress callback`

Comment: Yes, I agree. The code doesn't take that into account, sadly.

Comment: @robertklep Tested :> How do you think about this API? I see that library has "349 downloads in the last day"

Comment: I would agree that when there's only one callback given, it should be the result callback. But I think it might just be an oversight of the developer that it doesn't check for three arguments being passed instead of four; it's probably not intentionally done like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use bcyrpt-nodejs if thats what you prefer,but you have to edit the following section in bCrypt.js

```
if(!callback) {
    throw "No callback function was given."
}
```

and replace it with

```
if(typeof callback == 'undefined') {
    callback = progress;
    progress = null;
}
```

then in your code, just have this;

```
 require('bcrypt').hash(values.password,null,null,function passwordEncrypted(err,password){
```

Answer (score 0):

use bcyrpt.compareSync instead of bcypt.compare. It doesn't require a callback